# Open http:// links from Notepad++ all at once

Tags: notepad++

i have a list of `http` links in my notepad++ i want to open them all at once, how i can do that? i tried all the solution and shortcuts i did not get any good result.

Example:

```
http://example1.com
http://example2.com
http://example3.com
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try CMD batch script

```
FOR /F %%link IN (<your text file.txt>) DO  start chrome %%link
```

Comment: %%link was unexpected at this time.

Comment: If you are directly running the cmd then use this 
FOR /F %l IN (<your text file.txt>) DO  start chrome %l

Comment: i tried the bash file, it does not open any chrom or firefox, and i tried this solution direct from CMD i got this error, < was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Please share the exact cmd you are trying now. Are you replacing <your text file.txt> with yours ?

Comment: i tried this FOR /F %%link IN (<mailer.txt>) DO  start firefox %%link  and also this FOR /F %%link IN (<mailer.txt>) DO  start chrom %%link they are in a file cmd.sh I'm getting the same problem

Comment: no <>. use this FOR /F %l IN (mailer.txt) DO start firefox %l

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96554/discussion-between-vishal-santharam-and-snipercoder).

Comment: This worked - FOR /F %I IN (temp.txt) DO  start chrome %I

Comment: Thanks for the Firefox command @VishalSantharam, it worked great!